# Whatsapp link by using a shortcode

Tags: wordpress, whatsapp, shortcode

I made a custom field "Mobile Number" and I need when a visitor clicks on that phone number, it opens a Whatsapp chat. How I can do it?

I tried many methods like:

`https://wa.me/[mobile_number]`
and
`https://wa.me/{{mobile_number}}`

nothing worked!

---

Please note as I mentioned in the title, I want to get the whatsapp link by using the shortcode!

Because I have a site where the members can post listings therefor I want when a member adds his number it converts to a whatsapp link

Comment: The number should be in international format (prefixed with country code), without any non number char, so, eg for an Italian number of 123456, it will be wa.me/39123456

Answer (score 2):

You should use [https://wa.me/[number]](https://wa.me/%5Bnumber%5D).
[number] has to start with your country code, without the `+`.

In addition, you can use:
[https://api.whatsapp.com/send/?phone=[number]](https://api.whatsapp.com/send/?phone=%5Bnumber%5D)
Again, [number] has to start with your country code.

Comment: I know that, but I want to use the shortcode method!. Because I have a site where the members can post listings therefor I want when a member adds his number it converts to whatsapp link

Comment: @Arsalan Could you give me a bit more information about your site? Which membership plugin do you use? Where are the fields located?

Comment: I made the field using ACF. The field name is mobile-number. I don't use any membership plugins.